# How to get json key values by another key value

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a JSON output like this:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Anna",
            "values": [
                {
                    "code": "Latin",
                    "grade": 1
                },
                {
                    "code": "Maths",
                    "grade": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Mark",
            "values": [
                {
                    "code": "Latin",
                    "grade": 5
                },
                {
                    "code": "Maths",
                    "grade": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get field `values` for `"name": "Anna"`. I am getting RestAssured Response and would like to use my beans to do that, but I can also use jsonPath() or jsonObject(), but I don't know how. I searched many topics but did not find anything.

Comment: Many JSON query libraries can do that.  E.g. library _Josson_, the expression for your solution is `items[name='Anna'].values` which produces a _Jackson_ `JsonNode`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JSONpath in REST ASSURED java want to extract the data which are in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72011011/using-jsonpath-in-rest-assured-java-want-to-extract-the-data-which-are-in-array)